# BarChart animated scroll problem in production

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented MPAndroid bar chart on my android app and the chart scrolls when I run in debug mode but when I generate a release APK and run the app the chart does not scroll.

I have implemented the scroll with animation feature for bar charts with  a lot of data as indicated on the documentation(Link to source: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport)

The code snippet for scrolling with animation:

```
barchart.moveViewToAnimated(10, barchart.getData().getYMax(), YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT, 2500);
```

The expectation would be the bar chart scrolls on both debug and production environment but somehow the chart does not scroll in production.

Any assistance on how to figure out the problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could also open an issue with the library >> https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues

Comment: I have opened an issue on the library >> https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/4549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by proguard which is enabled for release builds. I forgot to add an exception for mpandroid and it messed with the animations. Rookie mistake.

For future references here's the code to be added to proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.github.mikephil.charting.** { *; }
```

Source: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Proguard